how the distribution of conditional arrival time implies a poisson process
A well-known theorem of the conditional distribution on arrival time of a Poisson process is that

Theorem. Let $N=\{N_t: t\ge0\} \sim PP(\lambda)$ be a poisson process, $S_n := \inf\{t\ge0: N_t=n\}$ be the arrival time. Then
$$(S_1,...,S_n) |_{N_t=n} = (Y_{(1)},...,Y_{(n)}) \quad\text{in distribution}$$
where $Y_i \sim iid \space U(0,t)$ and $Y_{(i)}$ be their order statistics.

The problem is that, how to prove its reverse also holds, i.e.,

Let $N=\{N_t: t\ge0\}$ be a counting process, $S_n := \inf\{t\ge0: N_t=n\}, X_n=S_n-S_{n-1}$. $X_i \sim iid \space F(x)$ with $F(0)=0$, $\mathbb{E}|X_1|<\infty$. If there exists some $n\ge1$ such that for all $0\le s\le t$,
$$P(S_n\le s | N_t = n) = \left(\frac{s}{t}\right)^n$$
Then $N \sim PP$ is a poisson process.

I can only deal with the case $n=1$, i.e. $P(X_1\le s|N_t=1)=\frac{s}{t}$, by utilizing
$$P(X_1\le s|N_{s+x}=1) + P(X_1\le x| N_{s+x}=1)=1$$
and the conditional probability formula to finally arrive at $G(s+x)=G(s)G(x)$ where $G(x)=1-F(x)$. It implies that $G(x)=e^{-\lambda x}$ thus $F(x)=1-e^{-\lambda x}$, which means that $X_i \sim \text{Exp}(\lambda)$ thus $N \sim PP(\lambda)$ by somewhat another theorem.
